# Finding Rank in Excel based on the text values

Tags: excel

I have an excel with duplicates values and I am trying to rank them based on the times they repeat. Is it possible to do this in excel? I tried using countif and rank functions but was not able to achieve the result.

Here is an example

[image]

In the above example, the value: M4 is repeated thrice and in the corresponding output values are 1, 2, and 3.

I was able to achieve this in SQL by using Row_Number and Partition By but the data order gets messed up when i give order by clause.

I would appreciate if any formula for excel is provided for this kind of computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in B2 and drag down:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
```